# I have an android project source code, but eclipse can't detect it to import

Tags: android, eclipse

-I have this source code of project and i uploaded it on Dropbox.

[Project Source Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zlexteimklciru7/Contacts%20Book.zip)

-What i want to do to make exlipse to detect it and i import it to my projects list but nothing is showing in detections in both import projects and existing android code

I'm using adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321

I'm sorry if this a noob question and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it in my pc and it works well. The project is not the problem.

A common mistake is to copy the project in your workspace and try to import it in Eclipse from there. I don't know if it is a bug or not but it won't work.

Try to unzip the project in a folder on your Desktop and try to import it from there. When you select it, check the box "Copy project into workspace" if you want to have it in your workspace folder.

Comment: I always unzip the projects then, import but it's not showing in my the projects list to import.

Comment: can you please export the project from your eclipse and upload it again?

Comment: Here you go:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ldh18ortpplcu5m/ContactsTab.rar

Extract in your Desktop. In eclipse, Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace > Browse > Desktop > ContactsTab > Accept > (Check) Copy projects into workspace > Finish

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a new : "Android project from existing source" ?

I suppose you did but to be sure, here is the way to make it :

http://techforpassion.blogspot.fr/2013/03/Eclipse-create-project-from-existing-source.html

Hope this can help

Comment: used the same way, but it not showing in the projects list to import

Comment: You've exported that with eclipse ?

Comment: Can you check if the Manifest file isn't empty ?

Comment: Manifest file is not empty

Comment: May sound stupid but have you tried to restart Eclipse ? Try to copy the files directly in the workspace.

Comment: Have you tried to unzip it on the desktop, browsing to it and check "copy the file to my Ws" ?